# Django: Admin Restrict change permission but allow the user to view contents (ie retain the hyperlink)

Tags: django, django-admin

This question has been asked few times before but I haven't got a suitable answer.

1. In django admin dashboard, I want to remove the change button.
2. The add button should be aligned to left after removing the change
   button.
3. The hyperlink on model name should not be disabled when the change
   button is removed by setting false in `has_change_permission` method.
4. When clicked on the hyperlink one should only be able to view the
   contents. Nobody should be allowed to change the contents.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it can be done. One would have to override the main admin index.html template, and in there make all custom changes they wish.

For example:

```
{% if model.perms.change %}
     <td><a href="{{ model.admin_url }}" class="changelink">{% trans 'Change' %}</a></td>
{% else %}
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
{% endif %}
```

could be changed with just:

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

as far as "Add" going to left one would have to redesign the table (it depends on haw far exactly link would have to be.
Also all of other points in question could be redone in this fashion.

My emphasis at this point would be to encourage not to override directly in the site packages, but instead override it with the creating index.html in global templates/admin folder. Even this has to be considered and done if absolutely necessary.